# Ansible-Galaxy install from tarball stuck on establishing connection to galaxy.ansible.com

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to install an ansible collection via ansible-galaxy. However, the programm is stuck during the step *Initial connection to galaxy_server: https://galaxy.ansible.com* and I have no idea what the problem could be. Thinking there might be a problem with the connection to the server, I manually downloaded and supplied the collection as tarball. However, that does not change anything. Any ideas what I might be missing?

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ~/Download/ansible.posix-1.3.0.tar.gz -vvvv
ansible-galaxy 2.5.1
  config file = /home/philipp/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/philipp/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-galaxy
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) [GCC 7.5.0]
Using /home/philipp/.ansible.cfg as config file
Opened /home/philipp/.ansible_galaxy
Processing role collection 
Opened /home/philipp/.ansible_galaxy
Initial connection to galaxy_server: https://galaxy.ansible.com
```

**Update**

Apparently, it isn't stuck, but super slow. While typing the question the program continued.

```
ansible-galaxy 2.5.1
  config file = /home/philipp/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/philipp/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-galaxy
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) [GCC 7.5.0]
Using /home/philipp/.ansible.cfg as config file
Opened /home/philipp/.ansible_galaxy
Processing role collection 
Opened /home/philipp/.ansible_galaxy
Initial connection to galaxy_server: https://galaxy.ansible.com
Base API: https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v1
- downloading role 'collection', owned by 
https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v1/roles/?owner__username=&name=collection
 [WARNING]: - collection was NOT installed successfully: Content has no field named 'owner'

ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Updated Ansible to `2.9.26`

After searching for the warning I found out that my ansible version was too old. After updating ansible to version `2.9.26` the installation via `ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix` seems to be working.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your answer as well :-)

Comment: Apparently, you have to wait to days before you can accept your own answer. That's why I haven't done this, yet ;)